# Fixed background in a TableView?

Tags: ios, swift

Fixed Background image in a TableView ?

Hey guys !

My first question as a Swift nOOb !

I'm trying to set up a fixed image as a background for my Table View. So far, the best option has been to include this in my ViewDidLoad :

```
let uluru = UIImage(named: "Uluru")
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: uluru!)
```

Not so great, right?

Especially because when you're scrolling, the image is tiled. Meaning, it's repeating itself. Does anyone has a solution via the IB or directly into the code to make it fixed ? Something like in CSS ?

I also tried the superview way :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

let uluru = UIImage(named: "Uluru")

let uluruView = UIImageView(image: uluru)

self.view.superview!.insertSubview(uluruView, belowSubview:self.view)
}
```

But no success at all!

And last but not least :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "Uluru")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Your ViewController extends from UITableViewController?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm a big beginner!

Comment: your view controllers can extend directly from UIViewController or UITableViewController. But, nevermind, the answer from matt should suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the `backgroundColor` property for this, and do not add any subviews. The table view is all ready for you to do what you want to do. Like this:

1. Create an image view (UIImageView) whose image is the desired image.
2. Make that image view the table view's *background view* (its `backgroundView` property).

Comment: You mean in the code or in the IB? In the IB I can add a color as a bg but I don't find the option for an image…